# Почему around_action вызывается 3 раза?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class SocketController < WebsocketRails::BaseController

  around_action do |controller, action|
    DEBUG "before #{controller.action_name}"
    binding.pry
    action.call
    DEBUG "after #{controller.action_name}"
    DEBUG "me: id = #{@me.id}, partner_id = #{@me.partner_id}"
    DEBUG "partner: id = #{@partner.id}, partner_id = #{@partner.partner_id}" if @partner
  end
  # остальные методы
end
```

и, к примеру, `event` `client_connected` приводит к следующему выводу

```
Started GET "/websocket" for ::1 at 2016-05-12 17:35:29 +0300
>>>> before client_connected
>>>> before client_connected
>>>> before client_connected
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "clients" ("session_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["session_id", "2_MX40NTU4NjExMn5-MTQ2MzA2MzczMDEwM35OQ3NaWElDcnhVSlMwMnpyc1cwaStUZzV-UH4"], ["created_at", "2016-05-12 14:35:30.170780"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-12 14:35:30.170780"]]
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
>>>> after client_connected
>>>> me: id = 73, partner_id = 
>>>> after client_connected
>>>> me: id = 73, partner_id = 
>>>> after client_connected
>>>> me: id = 73, partner_id =
```

Как так получается и как сделать, чтобы `around_action` вызывался единожды?

Backtrace после того как дебаггер вызвался в 4 раз:

```
From: /home/bjorn/Documents/rouletter/app/controllers/socket_controller.rb @ line 10 :

     5:   before_action :config_opentok, only: [:client_connected, :find_partner]
     6:   before_action :config_clients, except: [:client_connected]
     7: 
     8:   around_action do |controller, action|
     9:     DEBUG "before #{controller.action_name}"
 => 10:     binding.pry
    11:     action.call
    12:     DEBUG "after #{controller.action_name}"
    13:     DEBUG "me: id = #{@me.id}, partner_id = #{@me.partner_id}"
    14:     DEBUG "partner: id = #{@partner.id}, partner_id = #{@partner.partner_id}" if @partner
    15:   end

    /home/bjorn/Documents/rouletter/app/controllers/socket_controller.rb:10:in `block in <class:SocketController>'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:312:in `block in halting'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:313:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    /home/bjorn/Documents/rouletter/app/controllers/socket_controller.rb:11:in `block in <class:SocketController>'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:312:in `block in halting'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:313:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    /home/bjorn/Documents/rouletter/app/controllers/socket_controller.rb:11:in `block in <class:SocketController>'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:312:in `block in halting'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:313:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    /home/bjorn/Documents/rouletter/app/controllers/socket_controller.rb:11:in `block in <class:SocketController>'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:312:in `block in halting'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/bjorn/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/dispatcher.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in route'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/logging.rb:66:in `log_event'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/dispatcher.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in route'
```

Comment: @D-side, опубликовал

Comment: То-есть `action.call` и вызывает сам себя, но если поменять его на `yield`, то экшены вообще не вызываются и не заканчиваются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно вызывать `around_action` нужно, создавая отдельную функцию, а название исполняемого экшена можно получить в переменной `action_name` (а не в параметрах передаваемого блока)

Пример:

```
around_action :debug_me

def debug_me
  DEBUG "begin #{action_name}"
  yield
  DEBUG "after #{action_name}"
  DEBUG "me: id = #{@me.id}, partner_id = #{@me.partner_id}"
  DEBUG "partner: id = #{@partner.id}, partner_id = #{@partner.partner_id}" if @partner
end
```

Comment: Это странно. Согласно [документации](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-around_action) это синонимичные записи. Видимо. этот `around_action` добвляется несколько раз, но *символы* можно сравнить, а процы/блоки надёжно сравнить нельзя... Баг, вероятно? Попробуйте посмотреть, сколько раз **добавление** коллбэка выполняется.